# Basic Gravity/Projectile Question

Tags: forces, gravity, velocity, projectile

I have a really basic question before I start some code.

Can a projectile, launched into space, hit the opposite side of a planet with just its initial trajectory and force (assume an ideal, perfect sphere, no atmosphere-- just a rock with gravity)?
Like this:
[image]

My intutition says "Yes, of course it can", but I don't trust my intuition.

Comment: It can, but it will look much more symmetric and elegant than your drawing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can! The trajectory will be an ellipse with one focal point at the center of the planet and semi-latus rectum equal to the radius of the planet. The launch angle can range from parallel to the planet's surface (when launched at the orbital velocity) to 45 degrees relative to the surface of the planet, depending on the orbital eccentricity. The orbit will take the following trajectory, for $e\in(0,1)$, and taking $r_0$ as the radius of the planet:
$$r=\frac{r_0}{1+e\cos{\theta}}$$